# API Search only returns User Records but no Contact Records

Tags: rest-api, search

**Problem:**
Via Postman, I'm trying to search Contact Records with 'email address' as the query string.  I'm able to get a response but it only includes the User Record matches as the type.

```
{
   "searchRecords": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "User",
            "url": "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/User/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        "Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
]}
```

**Connected App API Settings**

My Oauth Scopes are as follows:

- Access the identity URL service (id, profile, email, address, phone)
- Manage user data via web browsers (web)
- Full access ((full)
- Perform requests at any time (refresh_token, offline_access

**My GET call =**
https://domain.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v58.0/search/?q=FIND+%7Bename@email.com%7D

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong or anything that I need to change?

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: To the person who downvoted - I see no reason for doing so. What specifically is wrong with this question and what suggestions do you have to rectify it?

Comment: You should check which particular user the OAuth corresponds to. If that user doesn't have access to the contact object, you would see any contacts in your results.

Comment: Thank you Casper.  I will look into this with my system admin.  I was thinking this might be a user permission issue.